# unable to update Google Drive document

Tags: ios, google-drive-api

A couple of days ago, my iOS application stopped updating Google Drive documents (creation still works). Here is the code I have been using successfully to create `GTLQueryDrive` queries for over a year:

```
query = [GTLQueryDrive queryForFilesUpdateWithObject:file fileId:file.identifier uploadParameters:uploadParameters];
```

Although executing this query returns no errors, documents are never updated. I tried changing this (since the above method doesn't seem to appear in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/ios/reference/ios-client/interface_g_t_l_query_drive)) to:

```
query = [GTLQueryDrive queryForFilesPatchWithObject:file fileId:file.identifier];
query.uploadParameters = uploadParameters;
```

However that returns this error:

> Error Domain=com.google.GTLJSONRPCErrorDomain Code=400 "The operation
>   couldn’t be completed. (Unsupported content with type:
>   application/json-rpc)"

Similar breakage has occurred [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14979599/google-drive-upload-api-error) with this method of query creation - can anyone point me to a more reliable way to update documents?

Answer (score 0):

There was a temporary glitch, this should be working again now.

Comment: indeed, this did seem to start working again briefly - however, thing seem to have broken again - same results as before, can you confirm?